# Unable to parse the format string

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I got the following error : unable to format the string  `@"( StudiesPatient.PatientName LIKE %@ AND ModalityName LIKE %@ AND StudiesPatient.PatientID LIKE @% )"`

I use the below code , any suggestion how to fix it

```
                          ]]; */
PatientName =    (PatientName != @"")? PatientName : @"*" ; 
Modality =       (Modality != @"" )? Modality : @"*"  ;
PataientID =     (PataientID != @"") ? PataientID : @"*"  ;

    NSLog(PatientName ) ;
    NSLog( Modality) ;
    NSLog( PataientID) ;


 [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"( StudiesPatient.PatientName LIKE %@ AND ModalityName LIKE %@ AND StudiesPatient.PatientID LIKE @% )",
                             PatientName,
                             Modality, 
                             PataientID              ]];
```

Comment: Any suggestion? Ok, I have a suggestion that has nothing to do with your problem: Don't use capital letters for variable names. Capital letters should be used for class names only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last placeholder is mixed up - `@%` instead of `%@`.